# A question on a quote from "Richard Deacon - In Between"

Tags: dialogue, documentary, subtitles, richard-deacon-in-between

There's a German documentary movie, called [Richard Deacon - In Between](https://youtu.be/yEfI0-TcC5I?si=vRoLE51u9PPuorKr) from 2013.

In the referenced link to the movie, you find a trailer - among others on YouTube. They all have in common that they start with a quote of Richard Deacon about "what's creative...".

In the German translation this quote reads as

> Was ist kreativ? Etwas, was dir durch den Kopf schießt, als interessant erkennen.

I would like to know how the original English quote reads. Unfortunately, it is blurred by the synchronized voice in the trailer and I can't recognize it or infer it on my own.

Comment: Google says *"What is creative? Recognizing something that comes to mind as interesting."*

Comment: @Paulie_D But that's not quite what he says. I understand "what's..." instead of "what is..." and something like "pops to your mind..." but here I'm unsure because it's blurred. Can you give a reference to google? Why have you removed the second question? It's important to me. If there's a Chinese version, I would like to know how this quote is translated...

Comment: You can ask as many questions as you like, but they have to be posted as separate questions. It's as simple is that. Please take the [Tour] to learn more. (The documentary seems to quote Richard Deacon, who is a British artist. Maybe the German translations are simply somewhat loose?)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The video you posted is unavailable, but it seems the trailer contains the quote you're talking about (at timestamp [0:15](https://youtu.be/-Z7-ZgD1eyk?feature=shared&t=15)):

I'm pretty sure what Deacon says is

> What's creative? Recognizing something that pops into your head as being interesting.

You can read along while listening to recognize the words. The German subtitles also closely resemble this English sentence.

Comment: The video might be unavailable in your country, but the trailer is always the same... Thank you, I'll ask a second question about the countries where this documentary appeared...